# Почему clipboardData.setData() блокирует работу с буфером обмена?

Tags: javascript

Есть код который обслуживает кнопку "Скопировать в буфер обмена":

```
export class ClipboardService {
    static copyToClipboard(toCopy: string) : void {
        document.addEventListener('copy', (e : ClipboardEvent) => {
            e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', toCopy);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        document.execCommand('copy');
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том, что после того как функция использована хотя-бы один раз, `Ctrl + C`, перестает работать, данные как бы застревают в буфере, и попытка копирования любого другого текста со страницы, горячими клавишами, или просто через правую кнопку мыши на выделенном тексте -> скопировать, не как не меняют его состояния. В буфере все время лежат данные скопированные с помощью `ClipboardService`.

Почему так происходит, как исправить это, так что-бы значение переписывалось в случае использования простого `Ctrl + C`?

Comment: Потому что вы не отцепляете обработчик, который нацепили в addEventListener — вот он и продолжает ловить абсолютно все копирования

Comment: @andreymal а как его отцепить?

Comment: removeEventListener, эти основы JS описаны в любом учебнике